# Como ler de um arquivo e salvar em variáveis em Java

Tags: java, string, arquivo

Estou tendo dificuldades, pois em um exercício de manipulação de arquivos em Java, o professor pediu para a gente criar um programa que pega o nome e a nota 1 e a nota 2 de duas provas e armazenar em um arquivo txt da seguinte forma: nome;nota1;nota2 só que depois em outro exercício ele pede para ler do arquivo os dados e calcular a media das notas salvando novamente os dados em outro arquivo da seguinte forma nome;nota1;nota2;media, como eu faço esta leitura e salvo os dados em variaveis String,float,float novamente ???

```
public class LeitorComun extends Leitor {
    private String nome;
    private  double n1,n2,media;
    String linha;

    public LeitorComun(FileInputStream arquivo) {
        super(arquivo);
    }


     @Override
    public void ler() throws IOException{
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(this.arquivo);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        do{
        this.linha = br.readLine();
              if(this.linha != null){
                  String [] palavras = this.linha.split(";");
                  System.out.println("nova linha ------------------------------------");
                  for(int i =0; i<palavras.length;i++){
                      System.out.println("palavra lida: "+ palavras[i]);
                  }
              }
          }while(this.linha != null);

    }
}
```

Comment: O que você já tentou fazer? Adicione na pergunta.

Comment: esse 'arquivo' que você quer ler é um .txt? ficou bem confusa sua pergunta. Talvez pra responder sua pergunta, você pode usar uma String[3] e converter as notas 1 e 2 com parseInt.

Comment: É por no segundo problema eu tenho que ler do arquivo.txt que criei, nele tem o nome e as notas, Ex:  Marco;11.5;22.3, como vou ler o nome e as notas e colocar nas variáveis nome,nota1,nota2, sendo que ao ler pelo InputStreamReader e  BufferedReader  eles leem a linha inteira, como vou separar os dados ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode criar um método simples para conversão de `String` para `double`:

```
private double converter(String texto) {
  return Double.parseDouble(texto);
}
```

E alterar seu método `ler` para:

```
@Override
public void ler() throws IOException {
  InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(this.arquivo);
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

  do {
    this.linha = br.readLine();

    if (this.linha != null) {
      double nota1;
      double nota2;
      double media;

      try {
        String[] palavras = this.linha.split(";");
        System.out.println("nova linha ------------------------------------");
        nota1 = this.converter(palavras[1]);
        nota2 = this.converter(palavras[2]);
        media = (nota1 + nota2) / 2;
        System.out.println(palavras[0] + "/ Média: " + media);
      } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        System.out.println("A linha \"" + this.linha + "\" contém erros");
      }
    }
  } while (this.linha != null);
}
```

Com o seguinte arquivo `notas.txt`:

> José;10;9
>
> André;5;8

O resultado é:

```
nova linha ------------------------------------
José/ Média: 9.5
nova linha ------------------------------------
André/ Média: 6.5
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, agora compreendi como funciona. O split tipo que quebra e separa as strings quando encontra " ; " ai depois é so converter.

Comment: @MarcoAntonioGomes Exato :) Não esqueça de escolher uma resposta que lhe atenda e marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!